# Kitchen Cabinet "Cracks" when opened

Tags: doors, cabinets, noise-reduction

A cabinet door in my kitchen makes a loud annoying "cracking" noise when I open and close it and I'm curious if this is something that I can fix simply by adjusting the adjustment screws or if there is actually something wrong with the hinge and it needs to be replaced.  I've tried slowly and meticulously adjusting the different adjustment screws to no avail.  Hoping that somoene else has come across this and can offer me some advice

Video with sound
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgv5herrklx4kl6/Video%20Oct%2009%2C%209%2024%2043%20PM.mov?dl=0

Photo of the hinge
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jjdgb91qyxchlh/Photo%20Oct%2009%2C%209%2025%2016%20PM.jpg?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: door is too close to frame. some soap or wd40 along the snagging edge would likely quiet it dramatically.

Comment: @dandavis, WD-40 is generally not safe on painted surfaces like a cabinet.  You could test it on an area first to see if it is safe, but I wouldn't assume.

Comment: @JPhi1618: cabinet is not painted, it's got a plasticy (melamine, formica) finish, should be fine w/ grease.

Answer (score 2):

Your hinge is adjustable for both how far away from door to door (front screw) and also how far from frame to door (back screw) . The hinges also have the non interesting door to door height alignment ( up down ) .

A nice video sample of that is found here:
https://youtu.be/Bd7sbYWGpXw

Comment: Thanks for the info and the video it was very helpful. After adjusting and adjusting I started to suspect it was the hinge itself and headed over to the hardware store and bought replacements. That did the job and the problem is now solved. Thank you all for the help!